# Using a drive taken by StoreMI in Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have an HDD+SSD drive I combined using AMD StoreMI on Windows. Then I installed Ubuntu on a different SSD. Can I mount and use the HDD I have for Windows on Ubuntu?

I added a picture showing what I see in Disks and `fdisk -l`
As you can see I can't start the HDD. Also I can't show, but the mount option is grayed out on the 3TB partition. Interestingly I can mount the 3MB filesystem whatever that is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use StoreMI enabled disks with Linux, because it is software based requiring special drivers in Windows. Without a port of the proprietary StoreMI software, you won't be able to access data within disks allocated through it.